# Count Query in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

May I ask someone why the two queries below don't output the same result using MSSMS? What do I have to add to the second one to get me the first output.

Table

```
|----------------------------------------|
|                 RoomBase               |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     CustomBit1      |       Date       |
|          1          |     2018-11-01   |
|          1          |     2018-11-01   |
|          1          |     2018-11-01   |
|          1          |     2018-11-01   |
|          1          |     2018-11-01   | 
|          1          |     2018-10-01   |
|          0          |     2018-10-01   |
|          0          |     2018-10-01   |
|          0          |     2018-10-01   |
|          1          |     2018-10-01   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Result from first query. [Desired Result.]

```
|---------------------|
|        Count        |
|---------------------|
|          2          |
|          5          |
|---------------------|
```

Result from second query. [Undesired result.]

```
|---------------------|
|        Count        |
|---------------------|
|         630         |
|         630         |
|---------------------|
```

630 is coming from the original amount of the data.

```
  SELECT ISnull(Count(1),0) FROM dbo.[RoomBase] 
  WHERE dbo.[RoomBase].CustomBit1 = 1 
  GROUP BY [RoomBase].Date



  SELECT (SELECT ISnull(Count(1), 0) FROM dbo.[RoomBase] 
           WHERE dbo.[RoomBase].CustomBit1  =1)
  FROM dbo.[RoomBase]
  GROUP BY [RoomBase].Date
```

All help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate more about desired result why `2` and `5` as the result? Your query base on `CustomBit1` with `1` have `7` and `0` have `3`..

Comment: Count(1) is going to count 1 for every row... seems unlikely that is what you want. Will never be null either. Maybe you want this `SELECT [Date], CustomBit1, count(*) FROM dbo.[RoomBase] GROUP BY [Date], CustomBit1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also filter your sub query by date

```
SELECT (
    SELECT ISnull(Count(1), 0) FROM dbo.[RoomBase] RB WHERE RB.CustomBit1  = 1
        AND RB.Date = [RoomBase].Date
    )
  FROM dbo.[RoomBase]
  GROUP BY [RoomBase].Date
```

Comment: alsfdhasldfhalksfdalksfd This worked!!! Can you explain it to me please???

Comment: your subquery and parent query dont have any relation. thats why it counts all rows.

Answer (score 0):

First Query will count all records that has `CustomBit1 = 1` after grouped them by `Date`.

The second one, will count all records that has `CustomBit1 = 1` (without grouping them), because you didn't include the group by inside the sub-query.

So, you'll have to do something like this in the second query :

```
 SELECT 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            COUNT(*)
        FROM RoomBase
        WHERE 
            CustomBit1 = 1 
        GROUP BY [Date]
    )
FROM RoomBase
```

Also, `ISNULL()` is not needed with `COUNT()` or `SUM()` functions. As these functions will always return an integer, and never return a `NULL`.

Comment: I tried your query. I get this error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: @ChunkyFresh yes, it's because it returns more than one value, I updated the query, it should returns either 2 or 5 (from your sample).

Comment: Thank you for your help ISR5. The answer by Serkan Arslan is what I was looking for.